# $_GET to access a page?

Tags: php, forms, url, get

I have a page `secured.php` with an URL containing a GET-parameter that comes from `index.php` by using `form method="post"` where after processing the script an user-id will be stored in a SESSION as well be added as a GET-parameter `u=12345` by a header-function that redirects to `secured.php?u=12345`.

By checking `if isset($_GET['u']){` the GET-paramater `u` is available, everything is fine. I can validate it and so on...

The problem now is that when submitting a form even here by using `form method="post"` on `secured.php?u=12345` the GET-parameter `u` will be used to header but when executing the header function the GET-parameter `u` for some reason won't be there anymore and `if ( !isset($_GET['u']) ){`will do some stuff that actually should not be done.

```
if ( !isset($_GET['u']) ){
   some stuff
} 

if (isset($_POST['something']) === true){
    header("Location: secured.php?u=12345&b=example");
}
```

I really would appreciate if there is someone who could help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You give us a description of what you want to happen, but absolutely nothing to look at *how* it's happening. *Something* is wrong in your implementation, but you're not showing us your implementation. There isn't anything we can do with the current information given.

Comment: In any case, on POST requests `$_GET['u']` will possibly not be set and get executed then. Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="GET"` resp. `=="POST"` to check whether a parameter is set or not corresponding to the request method.

Comment: The `!` is telling something like `is not`. So everying in that `if()` statement will execute without the parameter in the URL. If you remove the `!` your script will only execute if the parameter `u` is found in your URL

Comment: @syck Depends... you can perfectly POST to `action="foo.php?u=1234"`...

Comment: @deceze Okay... added a "possibly" =) But that's not the point... many people check for the presence of some variable where they should check for the request method and then get into trouble when changing the code.

Answer (score -1):

## Let check this:

## 1: index.php

```
<?php 
            session_start(); 
            $_SESSION['U_ID'] = '12345'; 
?>
<html>
    <body>

    <form action="secured.php?u=<?php echo $_SESSION['U_ID']; ?>" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
              <input type="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

## 2: secured.php

```
<?php

    if ( !isset($_GET['u']) ){
        //some stuff
    } else {
        if (isset($_POST["name"]) && $_POST["name"] != ''){
            $re_url = 'secured.php?u='.$_GET['u'].'&b=example';
            header('Location: '.$re_url);
        }
    }
?>
```

> Just small answer